# Is there a difference between \unvbox and \unvbox inside \output?

Tags: spacing, plain-tex, output-routine

By writing an output routine for grid typesetting I discoverd an inconsistency. Look at sequence of spaces in `\specialoutput` and at the end of the document. The same sequence of spaces obeys the grid in the output routine but somewhere else not.

MWE:

```
\catcode`@=11

\output{\ifnum\outputpenalty>-30000\relax \plainoutput \else \specialoutput \fi}

% Simulate a float box:
\setbox\tw@\vbox{%
    \strut This is a float box that should obey grid typesetting.
    This is a float box that should obey grid typesetting.
    This is a float box that should obey grid typesetting.
    This is a float box that should obey grid typesetting.
    \vrule height 14pt depth 4pt width 5cm% to simulate an object of random height
    \par\vskip\z@}% this makes \dp\tw@=\z@

% Fit the float box to the grid
\ht\tw@\dimexpr \ht\tw@/\baselineskip*\baselineskip\relax

\def\@setstrut{\setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height.7\baselineskip
        depth .3\baselineskip width\z@}}
\@setstrut

% First case: \unvbox in output routine
\def\specialoutput{% Simulate a "here" float
    \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}
    \dimen@\dp\z@
    \unvbox\z@
    \vskip-\dimen@
    \vskip1.3\baselineskip
    \copy\tw@
    \vskip\dimen@
    \vskip.7\baselineskip}% total \vskip is whole number times \baselineskip

% A primitive control if the grid is obeyed
\vtop to\z@{\noindent X \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X%
    \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X%
    \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X%
    \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X \break X\vss}
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
\vadjust{\penalty-40000}% insert float
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\strut

\setbox4\vbox{\strut Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\dimen@\dp4

% Use the same spacing as in \specialoutput, but here with no success
\unvbox4
\vskip-\dimen@
\vskip1.3\baselineskip
\copy\tw@
\vskip\dimen@
\vskip.7\baselineskip
{\bf Now the grid is not obeyed any more.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

\bye
```

So is there a difference between `\unvbox` inside the output routine and outside?[image]

Comment: I suspect the contents of box 255 aren't what you think they are.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? :)

Comment: I wasn't trying to be cryptic. I don't see the answer immediately and I don't want to spend an hour or more tracing through the weird things in your sample. If I did, I would start by comparing the box contents in the two cases (`\showbox`). I suspect the `\topskip` glue at the top of page contents (box 255) is not used in the box generated tin the other case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Other factors are at play in your example:

1. In your “inline” float you operated on a box with some depth, but you unskipped that, added more boxes and some glue. Now the baseline is at the bottom edge of the last `\vskip`. But it should rather be `\dimen@` higher with the `\vskip` immitating a depth. An interline glue is pasted that would normally be reduced by the depth of the preceding line but is not; as a result **all subsequent text will be shifted downwards by `\dimen@`**.

You can compensate for this by adding

```
\prevdepth=\dimen@
```

after the `\vskip`s (or after the `\copy\tw@`, it does not make difference). With this amendment you get

[image]

2. You can see that there still remains a tiny offset – that's the `\lineskip` (= `1pt`) added, because you are pasting a box taller than `\baselineskip` and TeX is cautious against pressing lines of a paragraph together with no space between them at all. Setting `\lineskip=0pt` (which you probably don't want in general, though) gives you a nice alignment:

[image]

None of this happens in the output routine, because you're just stacking boxes there (as opposed to lines of text) and it's the height+depth that matters rather than baselines.